# Automated test to ensure some site tunctionality is running OK

Tags: testing, functional-testing

OK guys, I'm have to check periodically if some functions on my site work fast and properly, so the question is what should I use for it? The tool should signal then something is going wrong and must have some eligible functionality.
I just thought about Google Chrome's extension iMacros, but it doesn't have some kind of sinnal system to notify me.
Is Selenium good for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium is great for automated testing, but if you want to make sure your site is up + notifications and statistics, I would recommend you to use some tool dedicated for that, that can check it also from multiple places. Examples: 
http://www.monitor.us/ 
http://www.uptimerobot.com/ 
http://www.pingdom.com/